# how to post html data to .aspx file and save data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

i want to crete some runtime control in asp.net hence i create one html file & for that i use JAVASCript for repeat that contols.i want to save the data enter into that control.but how it post to .aspx file & how the data save into database .please help me.

Comment: Make your question bit more clear..

Answer (score 1):

You can have a asp.net submit button on the page which posts everything on the server.

To read the values from the dynamically created DOM elements you will have to use the ASP classic like code - Request.Form['field-name']

Comment: Assuming that you are using jquery and you have a div with id 'mydiv'
Then you can do this to create DOM element $('#mydiv').append('<input type="text" name="mytext" />');
And then on server side you can use Request.Form("mytext") to get the value.